# Roles en symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

Tengo fijados  varios roles en Symfony jerarquicamente

```
      ROLE_1: [ROLE_2]                

      ROLE_2: [ROLE_3, ROLE_4] 

      ROLE_3: [ROLE_4]         

      ROLE_4: [ROLE_4]
```

en un twig necesito ejecutar una acción estrictamente para el usuario con ROLE_3, pero no lo he logrado con el siguiente condicional, porque Role 1 y 2 también contienen sus características

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_3') %}

    //Accion ver un elemento html
{% endif %}
```

Como puedo hacer que se ejecute esta condicional estrictamente para el usuario con role_3 (o sea que Role_1, Role_2 y Role_4 no lo puedan hacer), sin quitar las jerarquías?

Comment: No entiendo tus jerarquías de roles

Comment: @AdrianaHernández Role_4 es el mas básico y Role_1 el de mas privilegios, así  que:                                                                              Role_1 adquiere las características de Role_2.                                Role_2 adquiere las características de Role_3 y Role_4.                    Role_3 adquiere las características de Role_4 .                              Role_4 tiene las características básicas de usuario.

Comment: Hay un error conceptual entonces. Si ROLE_1 y ROLE_2 no pueden hacer una acción que ROLE_3 sí, no deberían heredar de él. Por otro lado, ROLE_2 hereda de ROLE_3 y este lo hace de ROLE_4, no es necesario que ROLE_2 también lo haga de ROLE_4.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo tienes estructurado, no lo puedes hacer. Pero tienes la opción de consultar el rol del usuario en cuestión y ver si es el rol que te interesa:

```
{% if app.user.role == 'ROLE_3' %}
{% endif %}
```

Normalmente, cuando implementas `UserInterface` o `AdvanceUserInterface` deberías tener un método getRole que también es accesible desde Twig. Si no fuera el caso, toca implementar un método para ello, es sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien pueden hacerlo como indicas, dentro de tu security config debes tenerlo configurado de una manera similar a esta

```
#app/config/security.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_1: ROLE_2
      ROLE_2: [ROLE_3, ROLE_4]  
      ROLE_3: ROLE_4
```

Finalmente, dentro de Twig

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
<p>Username: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Asimismo, también puedes denegar dentro de tu controlador

```
public function helloAction($name)
{
  if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
}
```

** Documentación extraída sobre Symfony 3.3

Comment: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` no es indicativo de ningún tipo de rol, como pregunta OP, simplemente indica si se está identificado en el sistema o no.